# Determine if array is in order AND the last element is 0

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting, ecmascript-6

how can I determine when the first X numbers of an array is in order AND the last element in 0? i.e the array is

```
1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,0
```

I currently have this, but this relies on the array always being the same, which isn't very flexibile

```
const sorted = (array) => {
    const solved = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 0]
    return (JSON.stringify(array) == JSON.stringify(solved))
}
```

Comment: What is `x` in "the first x numbers"?

Comment: Sorry, that should've probably been capitalised. X numbers (so whether the array is 15, 500 or 15000 numbers long, the first should be in order AND the last should be 0)

Comment: Sorry, what is the *value* of X? Do you mean *all* values except the last, or is there a segment that is excluded from this "first X"?

Comment: Sorry if i'm not being clear, but yes, all values other than the last (which should be 0) should be in order

Comment: OK, so what have you done to do this? You should iterate over the array and compare values. Where did you meet a problem?

Comment: I've given my example, i'm just not sure how else it can be done

Comment: what if you have only one or two elements in the array?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do something as simple as this:

```js
const checkArray = (arr) => {
    if(arr[arr.length-1] != 0){
        return false;
    }
    const nums = arr.slice(0, arr.length - 1);
    const sortedArr = [...nums].sort((a, b) => a - b);
    for (let i = 0; i < nums.length; i++) {
      if(nums[i] != sortedArr[i]){
        return false;
      }
    }
    return true;
}

console.log(checkArray([1,2,3,0])); // true
console.log(checkArray([1,2,3,4])); // false
console.log(checkArray([1,3,2,0])); // false
```

Basically the **steps** are:

- **Check if last element is 0**, else do an early return.
- **Create a sorted version** of the first part of the array (the one with the numbers)
- **Check if the numbers part is equal to the sorted array**. If any element is different return false

In the end you return true only if every condition is verified.

This is generic enough so that if in the future you want to change the sorting type you can just act on the `sort` function (for example if you want to make it descending).

Answer (score 0):

First define a generic function to verify that a segment of an array is sorted, then define a second function that uses the first to see the first values are sorted, and add a check for the final value:

```js
function isSegmentSorted(array, start=0, end=array.length) {
    for (let i = start + 1; i < end; i++) {
        if (array[i - 1] > array[i]) return false; 
    }
    return true;
}

function isSortedWithExtraZero(array) {
    return array.at(-1) === 0 &&
           isSegmentSorted(array, 0, array.length - 1);
}

var array = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,0];
console.log(isSortedWithExtraZero(array));
```

Answer (score 0):

We can use `every` function for that. With `!idx` we exclude the first index 0, then we check if `idx` is less than the length of your array. If so, check if it is sorted, else check it it equals to zero.

```js
const solutions = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 0];

const sorted = solutions.every((val, idx, arr) =>
  !idx || (idx < solutions.length - 1 ? arr[idx - 1] <= val : val === 0)
);

console.log(sorted);
```